# Issue in downloading excel from from nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have an endpoint which just fetches the entire data from a mongoose collection and convert it into an excel file then it gets downloaded in the client.
I am using **xlsx-to-json-lc** npm package to convert the mongoose data into excel.

```
.get(cors.cors,(req,res)=>{
var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
StockData.find({})
.then(async (resp)=>{
    var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(resp)
    var down = __dirname+'/public/exportdata.xlsx'
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb,ws,"Sheet1")
    await XLSX.writeFile(wb,down)

    //everything is fine till here.excel got created

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename=" + path.join(__dirname,'../public/exportdata.xlsx') )

    response.end()

})
```

the issue is when i click on download button from the frontend, excel is downloading but its not opening. got an error "file is corrupted".

In front-end( reactjs ) am using **file-saver** npm package

```
import fileSaver from 'file-saver' 

//some other code

axios.get("http://localhost:3000/excel",{},{
            headers: {
                    'authorization': "Bearer " + tok,
                     'Accept' : 'application/json',
                     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                     'responseType': 'arraybuffer' 
                 }}
                )
        .then((resp)=>{
            var blob = new Blob([resp.data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
            fileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'stockdata.xlsx');
            console.log('Downloaded')
        })
```

I gave **application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet** in the  **Accept header** of the request as well, but no success.Am not sure where it went wrong.can anyone help me to solve this please.

Comment: not opening how?  automatically?  did you check the http endpoint on its own?  does that work (like with a curl)?  How about the file once it is saved - how do you know that it is complete / not corrupted?

Comment: @akaphenom i checked with the endpoint. there is no issue in that.and i checked with making a req from postman as well no issues. I think the issue is in the frontend part